# How to bind the the value in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-binding

I have below template, how to bind the `defaultRelatedGuideUrl`  from the controller to the template?

```
[routerLink]="(editMode || readOnly) ? [] : ['/defaultRelatedGuideUrl/', link.slug]">
```

Controller:

```
@Input() defaultRelatedGuideUrl = 'myparam';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
[routerLink]="(editMode || readOnly) ? [] : ['', defaultRelatedGuideUrl, link.slug]">
```

Comment: It won't work, i tried

Comment: My bad, I edited. Try this.

Comment: Did it work? @Rijo